# JavaScript is not allocating needed size for ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, memory, arraybuffer

I tried to run this code to allocate a ArrayBuffer:

```
var data = new ArrayBuffer(336000000);
console.log(data.byteLength); // outputs 125829120
```

Does anyone know why the number if bytes is not allocated? Chrome don't give me any errors / warnings.

This problem is not on every platform, but on several like on Galaxy S6 (Android Browser)

Comment: That's 336 megabytes. Perhaps you only have access to 125 megabytes of memory?

Comment: It outputs `336000000` just fine for me. I put it in the console on Chrome.

Comment: @NeilDocherty wouldn't it be dependent on the resources available? I'd expect you'd have more memory to utilize on your computer over a S6.

Comment: @Kris, your right. I didn't even register that he wrote that he was on mobile.

Comment: Interesting, Firefox also does this. Not for that amount, but if I try to allocate 3GB it gives me only 1GB. Would have expected an exception instead of this.

Comment: For reference, [here's the ArrayBuffer constructor in the ECMA 6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraybuffer-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to allocate more memory than is available. However, according to the spec, this should raise an exception rather than returning you a smaller buffer:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createbytedatablock

> Let db be a new Data Block value consisting of size bytes. If it is impossible to create such a Data Block, throw a RangeError exception.

And the previous spec https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#5

> If the requested number of bytes could not be allocated an exception is raised

So if your browser is returning a smaller buffer rather than throwing an exception, it's non-compliant.

Comment: Look at the Compatibility array in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer. I think the question marks in the line about "new throws" is relevant.

Comment: @Barmar my read is that that's just about the fact you're supposed to use `new ArrayBuffer(x)` rather than just `ArrayBuffer(x)`, and questioning whether the browsers allow the non-`new` version or throw an exception, i.e. not related to the size issue